# Solving analytic gradient of loss function for neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

Please note that I am talking in about *theory* rather than ''what someone would do in a real, practical situation''.

Given a multi-layer Perceptron with at least 1 hidden layer, and sigmoid (or other non-linearities), and a loss function, let it be a quadratic loss function such as 
$L= ||\phi(X,W)-Y_{target} ||_{2}^2$, where $\phi(X,W)$ is the output of the net, W are the weights, X the data matrix, $Y_{target}$ the correct labels. 
I think it does not make sense to solve for $\nabla_W L = 0$ to find a minimum ?
I think it does not because, first of all, the function $L$, even though being ''the square of something'', is non-convex (possibly very complex with many ''hills'' and ''valleys'') and there can be many different values of $W$ giving a value of 0 for the gradient. Moreover, these points (W) where the gradient $\nabla_W L = 0$ could also be maxima rather than minima! Therefore, I think solving $\nabla_W L = 0$ would only make sense if $L$ is convex.

Can someone with good theoretical background answer this/confirm/complete this please?

Comment: Any minimum satisfies $\nabla_W L = 0$. The converse isn't true in general, but might hold for convex functions.

Comment: Are you [cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3248500/339790)? That is impolite.

Comment: [Also posted on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248500/).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. Given that you have already accepted an answer there, I will close this question for now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been crossposted on Mathematics: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248500/analytic-gradient-solving-for-non-convex-neural-network-loss-functions